# Change baseline of text

Tags: vertical-alignment

Is there a way to change the baseline of different text with different font sizes so that they are vertically center-aligned?

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello {\small Hello} {\scriptsize Hello} {\tiny Hello}

World {\small World} {\scriptsize World} {\tiny World}
\end{document}
```

The output aligns text to the baseline at the bottom of every line.
I want the text to align the text vertically in the center of every line.

Comment: size changes do not take an argument so _all_ of your commands apply to the rest of the document.  The syntax is `{\small Hello}`

Comment: Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, define `\vc` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\vc#1{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}

\vc{Hello} \vc{\small{Hello}} \vc{\scriptsize{Hello}} \vc{\tiny{Hello}}
\vc{World} \vc{\small{World}} \vc{\scriptsize{World}} \vc{\tiny{World}}
\end{document}
```