# How can I make the height of summation and fraction the same?

Tags: equations, overleaf, height

I was wondering if I could get some help with this. I want to align the heights of fraction and the summation. The summation is positioned too low compared to the fraction. How can I acheive this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\[\Lambda_{entry} =\frac{\psi/(1-\delta)}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}} + \frac{m_{I}(1-\Phi)}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}} \sum^{}_{(\tilde{g},\tilde{b}) \in \{(g,b)\}}\hspace{0.1em}f_{\tilde{g},\tilde{b}-1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you'd try it, your code snippet doesn't compile. Please add the missing minimal parts. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. I edited.

Comment: @Anonymouslylost Can you make a sketch which shows how you would like to change the alignment? The central axis seems to be perfectly aligned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3GHx.png

Comment: I hope something like the highest point of the summation is aligned with the highest point of the fraction. The current version looks like someone hammered the summation to below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hope something like the highest point of the summation [symbol] is aligned with the highest point of the fraction.

Be careful what you ask for...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' directive
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\scalebox' directive
\newcommand{\bigsum}{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\displaystyle\sum$}}}}}
  
\begin{document}

\[
\Lambda_{\mathrm{entry}} =
  \frac{\psi/(1-\delta)}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}}
+ \frac{m_{I}(1-\Phi  )}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}} \times
  \bigsum_{\mathclap{(\tilde{g},\tilde{b})\in\{(g,b)\}}}
  f^{}_{\tilde{g},\tilde{b}-1}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks a lot better. Maybe I'm too sensitive. It's kind of annoying that the position of tilds are different between g and b and that -1 is bigger than b as well. Would there be a nice package to control these aspects? Perhaps I should open a new post.

Comment: @Anonymouslylost - I disagree with your claim that "-1 is bigger than b". The objective "the position of tild[e]s are different between g and b" is another one of those "be careful what you wish for" items.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about what you meant? Do you mean I should be cautious in changing  basic configurations?

Comment: @Anonymouslylost - IMNSHO, there are excellent typographical and aesthetic reasons for *not* placing the tilde symbols at the same height for `\tilde{g}`, `\tilde{t}`, and `\tilde{b}`. E.g., if you define `\newcommand\xtilde[1]{\tilde{#1\mathstrut}}`, compare the appearances of  `$\tilde{g}\ \tilde{t}\ \tilde{b}$` and `$\xtilde{g}\ \xtilde{t}\ \xtilde{b}$`. Incidentally, are you familiar with what Ralph Waldo Emerson had to say about [foolish] [consistency](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored)?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546690
\newcommand\vc[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[\Lambda_{entry} =
  \frac{\psi/(1-\delta)}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}} +
  \frac{m_{I}(1-\Phi)}{\psi/(1-\delta) + m_{I}}
  \hspace{0.3em}
  \vc{$\displaystyle\sum_{(\tilde{g},\tilde{b}) \in \{(g,b)\}}
    \hspace{-1em}
    f_{\tilde{g},\tilde{b}-1}$}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the argument of `\vc` should be just the (suitably scaled) summation symbol, and should not include the range of summation.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much !